# How much do stars brighten as they age?

Tags: stars, worldbuilding-resources

Typical worldbuilding resources give some approximate equations for the luminosity of a main sequence star as a function of its mass, e.g. L = M<sup>4</sup> (relative to the Sun's mass and luminosity, for stars close in mass to the Sun). But main sequence stars grow brighter as they age. Are there any resources that give some approximate equations for a star's luminosity (and other parameters like diameter and temperature) as a function of both mass *and* age?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this definitely belongs on Astronomy or Physics SE rather than Worldbuilding.

Comment: I disagree with the close votes - the question's asking about resources and science very much related to worldbuilding.

Comment: @HDE226868 It's just directly asking how some physics is supposed to work. No specificity or nuance related to worldbuilding. By your logic, you could transplant almost any general physics question into worldbuilding.

Comment: Just so you're aware Matt, "real world" queries *can be on topic* here in Worldbuilding, but you need to be asking in light of your own fictional world. It's okay to ask about star luminosity, but you still need to tell us what problem in your fictional world you're trying to address.  And quite frankly, if there's no specific fictional issue you're facing, then this question would still be a poor fit for Worldbuilding. Though not Astronomy.